# How to perform XML variable substitution on mailSettings file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a Web.config file with the following system.net mailSettings attribute:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp configSource="mailSettings.config" />
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

mailSettings.config file is located under project sub root level and contains just the following lines:

```
<smtp from="reports@companyxyz.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
  <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="587" userName="" password="" />
</smtp>
```

We want to store the userName and password attributes as variables (eventually in the Azure Key vault but thats outside the scope here) in the release pipeline, and in the Azure App Deployment task (yaml below) there is an option for XML variable transformation/substitution.

```
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.ConnectedServiceName)'
    appType: '$(Parameters.WebAppKind)'
    WebAppName: '$(Parameters.WebAppName)'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: false
    RenameFilesFlag: false
    enableXmlTransform: true
    enableXmlVariableSubstitution: true
```

[image: image.png]

I have enabled it, but how will it know to transform the mailSettings.config template file?

This is the description of the XmlVariableSubstitution switch:

Variables defined in the build or release pipelines will be matched against the 'key' or 'name' entries in the appSettings, applicationSettings, and connectionStrings sections of any config file and parameters.xml. Variable Substitution is run after config transforms.

Note: If same variables are defined in the release pipeline and in the environment, then the environment variables will supersede the release pipeline variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case standard replacement will not work as you already found out that:

> Variables defined in the build or release pipeline will be matched against the 'key' or 'name' entries in the appSettings, applicationSettings, and connectionStrings sections of any config file and parameters.xml. Variable Substitution is run after config transforms.

You can still achieve your goal by using extension - [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

For default task configuration you need to change your file to have tokens defines as `#{VARIABLE_NAME}#`. So in your case it would be:

```
<smtp from="reports@companyxyz.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
  <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="587" userName="#{USER_NAME}#" password="#{PASSWORD}#" />
</smtp>
```

Also make sure you place correct target file.

Comment: Interesting! I installed Replace Tokens, what do you mean by ”Also make sure you place correct target file.”? Like the path you mean?

Comment: Yes, path to your file.

Comment: if i created pipeline variables, `userName` and `password`, in the config file, they should be: `userName="#{userName}#" password="#{password}#"` right? also do i place this task before Azure App Deploy task? or after?

Comment: ok so slight change in requirement: instead of replacing the username and password values, we want to replace this line in the web config: `<smtp configSource="mailSettings.config" />`
with a pipeline variable whose value will be `<smtp from="reports@companyxyz.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
  <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="587" userName="" password="" />
</smtp>`. Also because the developer doesnt want to change the web config file to accomodate prefixes and suffices required by the Replace Tokens task, we want to use custom Token Prefix, as such: `<mailSettings>`