# How to change connection string in web.config for a asp.net application deployed on a azure VM

Tags: asp.net, azure, devops

I have a asp.net application which is deployed on a azure VM. Devops pipeline is used to build and deploy the code. Now I need to deploy it on production VM. How can I change connectionstring in the web.config as per the environment (dev, production etc.)?

Comment: To Configure multiple environments for  WebApps, it is recommended to deploy your application in Azure WebApp.

Comment: Did you try "File transforms and variable substitution" in Azure DevOps?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using IIS web server on Azure VM for hosting your asp.net application.

Azure Pipelines has [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops) with File transforms and variable substitution options.

[image]

You will need to use "XML variable substitution" or "XML transformation" options to replace values for you Connectionstring in the web.config per the environment (dev, production etc.)

Another option is using extension - [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

For default task configuration you need to change your file to have tokens defines as #{VARIABLE_NAME}#. Here is an example:

```
<smtp from="reports@companyxyz.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
  <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="587" userName="#{USER_NAME}#" password="#{PASSWORD}#" />
</smtp>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops

[How to perform XML variable substitution on mailSettings file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614382/how-to-perform-xml-variable-substitution-on-mailsettings-file)